# "Должен": какая это часть речи?

Tags: части-речи

Нашла такую забавную картинку:

[image]

Может быть, я просто уже забыла правила русского языка, но какая же часть речи слово "должен"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Я согласна с Ларf в том, что это **краткое прилагательное**. Во многих словарях эту тему как-то обходят, но  ***в словаре Кузнецова*** читаем:
ДО́ЛЖЕН -жна́, -жно́; **нареч**., в функц. сказ.
С инф. Обязан (делать что-л., обладать каким-л. качеством). Шахматист д. закончить партию. Хозяйка должна приготовить завтрак. Ты д. быть добрее. // О том, что совершится обязательно, непременно или может совершиться. Д. скоро вернуться. * Всё на земле должно измениться мало-помалу (Чехов). // Вынужден, принуждён. Чтобы выздороветь, я должен принимать лекарства...(Большой толковый словарь русского языка. - 1-е изд-е: СПб.: Норинт. С. А. Кузнецов. 1998)

Но с тем, что это наречие, согласиться очень сложно, потому что наречие - неизменяемая часть речи, а ДОЛЖЕН изменяется и по родам, и по числам. В школе мы говорим об этом слове, как о прилагательном. О слове РАД тоже.

Answer (score 5):

Должен - это краткое прилагательное. Полная форма "должный".

Answer (score 2):

Кажется это предикатив:
Предикативы, категория состояния, безлично-предикативные слова, предикативные слова, предикативные наречия, - слова, обозначающие нединамическое состояние и выступающие в функции главного члена (сказуемого, предиката) однокомпонентного (односоставного, безличного) предложения.

http://russkiyyazik.ru/707/

Comment: Пишите без "кажется", если уверены.

Comment: Предикатив это член предложения,а не часть речи.

Answer (score 0):

Имя состояния наряду с нужно, можно

Comment: Подробнее бы хотелось "про имя состояния". Термин не для всех понятный и привычный.

Answer (score 0):

Это модальный глагол, обозначающий отношение к действию.