Какой частью речи является слово "должен"?
Тема уже обсуждалась на форуме, но мнения очень разные. К тому же отвечающие в недостаточной мере использовали источники для подтверждения своей точки зрения.
Каков же правильный ответ?
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/20738/Должен-какая-это-часть-речи
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/428605/Должен-что-за-слово-такое


В современной грамматике это МОДАЛЬНОЕ КРАТКОЕ ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ (со связкой): должен, обязан, рад, готов, согласен, способен, не властен, намерен, вынужден.  Начальная форма: должен.Из учебника для педвузов Г.И. Кустова "Синтаксис современного русского языка" (2013)

От других модальных предикативов эта часть речи отличается наличием словоизменения: должен, должна, должны. В общем же случае это разновидность МОДАЛЬНЫХ ПРЕДИКАТИВОВ, куда относятся и неизменяемые слова вида нужно, надо, нельзя.

Из Русской грамматики под ред Н. Ю. Шведовой и Лопатина В. В.(1990), стр. 262:

В современном языке модальные предикативы являются самостоятельной частью речи и  НЕ СООТНОСЯТСЯ с качественными наречиями и краткими прилагательными.

Неопределенность в определении этой части речи нежелательна, так как морфологический разбор слова имеет разные варианты относительно начальной формы. Об этом говорится в Сети, но разница между вариантами не объясняется по существу, например здесь:
Слово «должен» имеет 2 разных морфологических разбора. Вариант разбора 
зависит от того, в составе какого словосочетания или предложения слово 
находится. Выберите подходящий вариант для вашего случая.


Пользователи также с трудом ориентируются в этом вопросе, что видно из ответов.


Так нужна ли неопределенность в этом вопросе? Почему до сих пор вопрос не решен однозначно хотя бы для школьного уровня?

Ну ведь в лингвистике всегда существуют разные мнения. У разных учёных разные взгляды.

Серж, посмотрите в словаре должный https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=должный&mode=slovari&dicts[]=71&dicts[]=48&dicts[]=42  и должен https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=должен&mode=slovari&dicts[]=71&dicts[]=42  Что между ними общего?  Значение разное, синтаксическая роль разная, грамматические формы не совпадают. Вот разбор https://aznaetelivy.ru/morfologicheskij-razbor-slova/dolzhen   Вот еще  https://rustxt.ru/morfologicheskij-razbor-slova/должен

Почему бы не называть должен предикативом или модальным кратким прилагательным, но только не просто кратким прилагательным  А здесь вообще прилагательное https://synonyms.su/morphology/d/dolzhen   Как вам это нравится?  Тоже разные мнения в лингвистике? Мне они кажутся необоснованно разными.

А вот у Ефремовой https://gufo.me/dict/efremova/должен  Там два варианта: прилагательное и предикатив. Но прилагательное должен кому-то,  а предикатив с неопред. формой. // Сложно учиться в школе при таком разнообразии мнений у лингвистов.  И почему бы не ориентироваться на Грамматику Шведовой или Синтаксис Кустовой (для педвузов)?
